# Elastic search - Index business listing the right way

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-query

A business listing website, which index the business, categories, product service, business descriptions, address, postcode.

I have two search text box on the front page, one for `business name search` and the other is for `address, postcode" search`.

I'm wondering, how can I index my business description and categories and product and service, so when people search for a business name it show up that business name, and if someone search for a categories, then it show business in that category.

The current experience, when someone search for a `doctor` on the `business search box`, it show doctors medicine and also a product called `doctor cleaner` ..etc  How can I only limit to doctor medicine.

### Here's my mapping

```
"busness_listings": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "search_api_aggregation_3": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "search_api_aggregation_2": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "search_api_aggregation_1": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "field_business_address:postal_code": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "is_new": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "sticky": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "field_silver_brands": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "search_api_language": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "field_category": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "field_silver_product_services": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "field_business_address:locality": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "field_bronze_product_services": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "field_products_services": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "title": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "field_silver_category": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "type": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "status": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "nid": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "field_address": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "promote": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "body:value": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "field_business_address:dependent_locality": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "field_business_address:administrative_area": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "field_bronze_brands": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "url": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "field_gold_brands": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "field_phone": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "edit_url": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "field_bronze_category": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: It would be nice to tell what have you done so far, your current index mapping, queries, sample docs so that we can build on top of it.

Comment: thanks mate, I've added in my mapping, hope it will help.  Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: fyi @OpsterESNinja

Comment: Still, you have not provided your queries and sample docs and I fear you are asking a lot here w/o providing many details. also please mention ES version u are using?